# How to get jlibsvm prediction probability in multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am new to SVM. I am using **jlibsvm** for a *multi-class classification* problem. Basically, I am doing a sentence classification problem. There are *3 Classes*. What I understood is I am doing **One-against-all classification**. I have a comparatively small train set. A total of 75 sentences, In which 25 sentences belongs to each class.

I am making 3 SVMs (so 3 different models), where, while training, in *SVM_A*, sentences belong to CLASS A will have a true label, i.e., *1* and other sentences will have a *-1* label. Correspondingly done for *SVM_B*, and *SVM_C*.

While testing, to get the true label of a sentence, I am giving the sentence to 3 models and I am taking the *prediction probability* returned by these 3 models. Which one returns the highest will be the class the sentence belong to.

This is how I am doing. But I am getting the same *prediction probability* for every sentence in the test set for all models.

```
A predicted:0.012820514
B predicted:0.012820514
C predicted:0.012820514
```

These values repeat for all sentences in the training set.

The following is how I set parameters for training:

```
C_SVC svm = new C_SVC();
MutableBinaryClassificationProblemImpl problem;

ImmutableSvmParameterGrid.Builder builder = ImmutableSvmParameterGrid.builder();

// create training parameters ------------
HashSet<Float> cSet;
HashSet<LinearKernel> kernelSet;

cSet = new HashSet<Float>();
cSet.add(1.0f);

kernelSet = new HashSet<LinearKernel>();
kernelSet.add(new LinearKernel());

// configure finetuning parameters

builder.eps = 0.001f; // epsilon
builder.Cset = cSet; // C values used
builder.kernelSet = kernelSet; //Kernel used
builder.probability=true; // To get the prediction probability
ImmutableSvmParameter params = builder.build();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other better way to do *multi-class classification* other than this?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the same output, because you generate the same model three times.

The reason for this is, that [`jlibsvm`](https://github.com/davidsoergel/jlibsvm) is able to perform multiclass classification out of the box based on the provided data (`LIBSVM` itself supports this too). If it detects, that more than two class labes are provided in the given data, it automatically performs multiclass classification. So there is no need for a manually 1vsN approach. Just supply the data with class-labels for each category.

However, `jlibsvm` is still in **beta** and relies on a rather old version of `LIBSVM` (2.88). A lot has [changed](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/log). For a more intiuitive Java binding (in comparison to the default `LIBSVM` version), you can take a look at [zlibsvm](https://github.com/rzo1/zlibsvm), which is available via Maven Central and based on the latest `LIBSVM` version.